# Should I be able to filter on data and a partition key at the same time?

Tags: serverless-framework

Using the serverless framework to create a lambda that is consuming data off an AWS Kinesis stream.

Messages going onto the stream look like this.

`{ "id": "f1986417-0a4e-445f-b07a-e5527c0adc2f", "success": true, "result": "TagNotFound", "type": "Access", "tagId": "TEST:04E026D27A5884", "scanTime": "2023-07-31T21:29:52.600Z", "companyId": null, "createdAt": "2023-07-31T21:29:55.172Z", "scannedBy": "jjjjjj", "mobileId": "12435" }`

Filter pattern on the lambda looks like this.

`filterPatterns: - partitionKey: [ "MyPartitionKey" ] - data: tagId: - prefix: 'TEST:' success: [ true ]`

Question is, should this work? As long as I have a partitionKey filter, the data filter is ignored and all records regardless of prefix or success as passed to the lambda. If I remove the partitionKey filter the data key works as expected.

I cannot find any documentation indicating that this is expected behaviour.

I expect both filters to work together. I have tried removing the partitionKey filter to get the data filter to work. In this case, all the records on the stream have the same partitionKey anyway, so the filter is not actually necessary.

This is more of a learning thing at this point. I just want better understand if there is an underlying reason for this not working.